# How indirect file urls works?

Tags: php, url, download

A url is the direct link towards a resource as per my knowledge. I have experience with Apache and PHP, and I know that using .htaccess file, one may set a default file (like index.php) for a location where no need to provide end file name.

But for file links, one need to provide a direct link, having filename and extension like `somedomain.com/file.txt`. But recently I found some links, especially download links, that dont have a url with filename and extension.

For example, i tried to grab direct .mp4 file url for this youtube video www.youtube.com/watch?v=W1- L58y2uf4 , of resolution 1080p HD. Then I got a url (using clipconverter.cc) like;

http://r9---sn-25g7sne7.c.youtube.com /videoplayback?source=youtube& ip=2001:41d0:8:1f2b:3a0e:6049:6b4f:92 e9&expire=1378905654& sparams=cp,id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,sou rce,upn,expire&ipbits=48& upn=BgsjQ8lS424& cp=U0hWTVlLU19KTkNONl9RRVdHOkZIZ0 diYTFXLWRJ&key=yt1& id=5b5f8be7ccb6b9fe&mt=1378881529& ratebypass=yes&itag=37&sver=3& mv=m&fexp=903309,919391,910207,91 4071,916612,924606,929117,929121,92 9906,929907,929922,929127,929129,92 9131,929930,936403,925726,936310,92 5720,925722,925718,925714,929917,90 6945,929933,920302,906842,913428,92 0605,919811,913563,919373,930803,90 8536,938701,931924,936308,909549,90 0816,912711,904494,904497,939903,90 0375,900382,934507,907231,936312,90 6001&ms=au& signature=1DDD3BB4A46816E27075ADF1 3C84B810AD1DF72D.C9B4290CE7F0806A 3174E65DE3920F3AFDB06833& title=Kilimanjaro+-+ROBOT+%282010%29 +%2AHD%2A+1080p+%2ABluRay%2A+ Music+Video

The browser downloads the file perfectly. How this works? Where is the filename and extension in this link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please repeat:

> URLs !== files
>   URLs !== files
>   URLs !== files

When **requesting** a URL, your browser/HTTP client/whatever is sending an HTTP request to a web server, requesting the URL. The web server is free to respond to this request in any way it pleases. URLs have nothing at all to do with files on a hard disk. It's just a convenient default configuration that web servers look for files of the same name as the requested URL and serve those. But it could do anything else it wanted as well. It can start up a shell script which gets the requested URL passed as an argument, which in turn can output anything it wanted. The web server may be a Java application which processes the requested URL internally and responds with some content. The server could be anything and everything at all and it can respond by doing anything it wants to. A web server is just an application that listens on port 80 (or elsewhere) and answers incoming HTTP requests. The file system doesn't have to be involved at all.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably calling a script which depending on your parameters finds the file you want and before sending it, it modifies the headers to make your browser treat the file as a video file (and download it) and not as a regular html document

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header("Content-Type: application/zip");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
```